# Join table and applying filter?

Tags: sql

I have a question on this query forever and never figured it out, need some help and thanks in advance for all answers! 
I have table 1: Payment (storing historical payment info, I only look at one month data and only type#1 payment, so i need to apply two filters here)

Pymt

```
ServiceID InsuranceID Amount Month Type
1         A           $10    Jun15 1
2         A           $15    Jun15 1
3         B           $15    Jun15 1
4         C           $30    Jun15 1
5         D           $50    Jun15 1
```

Ins

```
Insurance ID    Name
A               AAA
B               BBB
C               CCC
D               DDD
```

Expected Result

```
Service ID  Insurance ID    Name    Amount  Month   Type
1           A               AAA     $10      Jun15   1
2           A               AAA     $15      Jun15   1
3           B               BBB     $15      Jun15   1
4           C               CCC     $30      Jun15   1
5           D               DDD     $50      Jun15   1
```

So there are two tasks here:
1. filter table 1 by Jun 15 and Type 1

2. add a new column"Name" in table 1 to indicate the name of the insurance WITHOUT adding new rows ( it is like a vlookup ) so monthly amount total is the same

I tried differnt joins and WHERE(filter) always added new rows to result which I don't want, please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on #2?  You say you don't want to add extra rows, but your expected result has an extra row added.

Comment: maybe not use `select * from`

Comment: Thanks for responding. My goal is to keep pymt table total amount the same after filling in the insurance name, so the result rows number should be the same as pymt table rows number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.ServiceID, i.InsuraneID, i.Name, p.Amount, p.Month, p.Type
from Pymt p
inner join Ins i on p.InsuranceID = i.InsuranceID
where p.Month='Jun15' and p.Type=1
```